# Page redirection on page refresh not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

I want to redirect to a page on page refresh. Below is my script.

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    alert("exiting");
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    return false;
});
```

Its not working. I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Are you getting an alert?

Comment: Chrome does not like alerts on exit, it should work in Firefox though.

Comment: yes.. I am getting the alert but the page is not redirected.

Comment: I am trying in IE. Also when I try to redirect on button click its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the browser cannot handle anything after **unload process is done**.

You should use `beforeunload` event instead.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() { 

    alert("exiting");
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :)

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){
   alert("exiting");
        window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
        return false;
});
```

Comment: try $(window) as @Orion :)